# Kotlin: FragmentManager inside fragment becomes null

Tags: android, kotlin

This is my code:

```
Places.initialize(context!!, getString(R.string.google_api_key))
        val autocompleteFragment : AutocompleteSupportFragment = fragmentManager?.findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment) as AutocompleteSupportFragment
        autocompleteFragment.setCountry("NO")
        autocompleteFragment.setPlaceFields(Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME, Place.Field.LAT_LNG, Place.Field.ADDRESS, Place.Field.ADDRESS_COMPONENTS))

        autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(object : PlaceSelectionListener {
            override fun onPlaceSelected(place: Place) {
                onPlaceSelectedOverride(place)
                Log.d("myTag", place.address + " - " + place.addressComponents + " - " + place.latLng)
            }

            override fun onError(status: Status) {
                throw RuntimeException()
            }
        })
```

Problem is the fragmentManager. Previously the code was placed inside onCreate() of the mainActivity, and the code had this difference.

```
val autocompleteFragment : AutocompleteSupportFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment) as AutocompleteSupportFragment
```

But on moving the code to another fragment, all sorts of problems came about. fragmentManager appears to be null. What is fragmentManager and how can I make this code function inside a fragment?

Comment: `"But on moving the code to another fragment, all sorts of problems came about."` where is the code that causes the errors?

Answer (score 1):

Try using childFragmentManager

```
val autocompleteFragment : AutocompleteSupportFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment) as AutocompleteSupportFragment
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're working with nested fragments, but if it's the case, you can try using childFragmentManager.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
val autocompleteFragment : AutocompleteSupportFragment = activity!!supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment) as AutocompleteSupportFragment
```